# What's a substitute for raw_input() in 3.6?

Tags: python-3.x, input, python-3.6, raw-input

```
e=input('what's your name?')

print('so you %s, %s, %s.' % (e,l,x))
```

I want to create a program where I'm required to answer my questions, but using input() just returns `[so you , , .]`.

Comment: You need to specify the language you're talking about. Is it Python 3? If so, add a tag and specify it in your post

Answer (score 9):

OK, I'm guessing you're talking about Python 3.6.

First mistake:

```
 e=input('what's your name?') #notice how you're using too many "'"
```

Correct:

```
 e=input("what's your name?")
```

Second mistake:

```
print('so you %s, %s, %s.' % (e,l,x)) 
#you did not specify l and x, so Python will throw an error
```

Correct:

Declare and assign values to the "l" and "x" variables before using them.
Just make an input like you did to "e", for example:

```
l=input("what's your L?")
```

---

In Python 3 there are no `raw_input`s because *all* inputs are `raw_input`s.
 It took away Python's 2 regular `input` because it was too problematic. So Python's 3 `input` == Python's 2 `raw_input`.

To use Python's 2 regular `input` in Python 3, use `eval(input())`. For more information, see: http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/whatsnew/3.0.html